# Solving this ODE (Euler's form?)

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am having a struggle solving this ODE:

$$(1-y)y''+2y'^2=0$$

I tried to solve this by changing it to Euler's form, but could not go any further. Can anyone solve this for me? And if possible, can you show me how to solve the equation by step? Thank you.

Comment: **Hint:** Let $$v = y'$$

Comment: If you do such a transformation, how do you deal with 1-y?

Comment: @galoiasuteva It'll be more obvious once you work it out. You'll end up with $y$ on one side of the equation, and $v$ (and its derivatives) on the other, after which you can antidifferentiate separately

Comment: Oh yes! Now I got what you mean. Thank you so much for both of you two!

Answer (score 1):

Following Moo's hint,

Here $' \equiv \frac{d}{dx}$. Let $v = y'$. Then $y'' = v' = \frac{dv}{dy} \cdot \frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{dv}{dy} v$,
\begin{align}
  (1 - y)y'' + 2(y')^2 &= 0\\
  \Rightarrow (1 - y)\frac{dv}{dy}v + 2v^2 &= 0\\
  \Rightarrow v\left((1 - y)\frac{dv}{dy} + 2v \right) &= 0
\end{align}
Hence, we have $v = 0$ or $\left((1 - y)\frac{dv}{dy} + 2v \right) = 0$.

If $v = 0$, then $y(x) = c_1$ for some $c_1 \in \mathbb{R}$.

If $\left((1 - y)\frac{dv}{dy} + 2v \right) = 0$, then
\begin{align}
  (y - 1)\frac{dv}{dy} &= 2v\\
  \Rightarrow \int \frac{1}{2v} dv &= \int \frac{1}{y - 1} dy\\
  \Rightarrow v &= c_2(y - 1)^2,\ \exists c_2 \in \mathbb{R}\\
  \Rightarrow y' &= c_2(y - 1)^2 \\
  \Rightarrow \int \frac{1}{(y - 1)^2} dy &= c_2 \int dx\\
  \Rightarrow \frac{-1}{y - 1} &= c_2 x + c_3,\ \exists c_3 \in \mathbb{R}\\
  \Rightarrow y &= \frac{1}{c_2 x + c_3} + 1\\
\end{align}